# Linking to external stylesheets in Aptana

Tags: css, aptana, stylesheet

I'm new to Aptana Studio, and I'm afraid there's something I just don't understand about it. When I try to link to an external stylesheet located in the same folder as my .html file, it won't work.
Normally, you just place something like the following code in the head section, right?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Can someone please explain to me why this doesn't work?
I really like Aptana so far, but this is driving me mad.

Comment: Please post some code from top portion of your CSS file

Comment: This is the first part of my CSS file:
`body {
 margin:.5em;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 background-image:url(img/body-bg.jpg);
 background-position:top;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 color:#000000;  
 text-align:center;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:.9em;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct but I haven't heard good things about Aptana. If you only want to code in HTML CSS and JavaScript you surely want to use `brackets`

This is an awesome text editor with LIVE code preview in browser like firebug -

http://blog.brackets.io/2012/06/25/brackets-open-source-code-editor/

`Download the latest sprint:` https://github.com/adobe/brackets/downloads

Comment: It might be a bit too complex for me, I'm only a beginner with code.

Comment: By the way, do they support jQuery as well?